# Angular fetch data from API, want to only fetch the array

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I fetch data from API in my Angular project. I receive a lot of data, but a want to choose the data fetch. I only need  to fetch the "results" array. I don't know what I have to do in my function.

[image: This is all data fetch with my function]

[image: This is my function]

If you have a suggestion please tell me.

Comment: Seems like your API is a REST API, so response of API is decided from back-end of your project and not from front-end. Actually GraphQL provides you this functionality but that is different matter for now. 

You will have to check if your back-end API supports this type of behaviour or not.

Comment: It looks like you're a newer contributor here so welcome! Can you provide in-line code samples instead of links to images? See [Code Formatting Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for examples and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get right what you want to do is:

```js
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

...

searchMovies() {
  return this.http.get(...)
      .pipe(map((response: any) => response.results));
}
```

If the version of rxjs library you're using is < 5.5:

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

...

searchMovies() {
  return this.http.get(...)
      .map((response: any) => response.results);
}
```